# When using i18n in Next.js, what's the best strategy to make a page that's only available to one locale?

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, internationalization

My site uses Next.js's [Internationalized Routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing) which automatically creates a localised route for every static page.

For example, if I have the locales `gb`, `us` and `fr` - and set `gb` as the default - and I have a page with the filename `my-page.tsx`, I'd get:

```
http://localhost:3000/my-page/
http://localhost:3000/us/my-page/
http://localhost:3000/fr/my-page/
```

But sometimes I have pages that are just intended for the `fr` locale!

**What's the best strategy to create only one page for a specific locale?**

If I need only `http://localhost:3000/fr/my-page-just-for-fr/`, how do I prevent `http://localhost:3000/my-page-just-for-fr/` and `http://localhost:3000/us/my-page-just-for-fr/`?

I have considered [rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) and [redirects](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects), but I'd prefer if these unwanted pages were not generated in the first place!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can now answer my own question!

If you return `{ notFound: true }` inside `getStaticProps` (see [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/get-static-props#notfound)) then the particular page is not built and an attempt to go to that route will lead to a 404 error.

This can be returned conditionally for specific locales. So, for example, to exclude the `"fr"` locale from being built for a particular page, we can write:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ locale }) => {
  if (locale === "fr") {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {}, // my props generated at build time
  };
};
```

Note that this problem and solution relate to Next.js's older [Pages Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages) and not the newer [App Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app).